# Разница между бандеры, бэндеры, биндеры и бендеры?

Tags: существительные

Это вообще русские или украинские слова?

Comment: А если все слова украинские? - можно с разницей  не разбираться? - сайт-то ведь РУССКОГО языка. Вы уж определитесь.

Comment: бэндеры - скорее всего фонетический вариант от "Бэндеры"/"бандеры", а вот где вы нашли "биндеры"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть **Бендеры**, город в Молдавии. Есть Остап **Бендер**, фамилия главного героя 12 стульев. Есть Степан **Бандера**, лидер украинских фашистов в 30-е - 40-е гг. ХХ в. От последней фамилии произошло слово "б**а**ндеровец".

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58993/discussion-on-answer-by---------).

Answer (score 1):

**Биндер**
(англ. binder)
*предварительное соглашение о намерениях между страхователем и страховщиком,* фиксирующее желание сторон заключить в последующем полномасштабный договор страхования, после чего биндер заменяется на страховой полис.
**Биндер** заключается в специфических случаях, когда урегулирование финансовой части договора требует особых условий.
*Словарь бизнес-терминов. Академик.ру. 2001.*

**Биндеры**
***или зажимы для бумаги*** – удобные офисные принадлежности, которые позволяют скрепить между собой документы либо прикрепить файлы или листы к жесткой основе (например, к планшету для письма, к папке).
Назначение зажимов для бумаги такое же, как и у степлеров – скреплять документы. Но документы, собранные с помощью биндера, можно «расшить» и переставить листы в произвольном порядке или вытащить часть страниц.
 При использовании степлера для расшивания понадобится антистеплер, который не всегда под рукой, а многочисленные перепрошивания стопки бумаг приведет к неаккуратному виду страниц.
[**биндеры**](https://www.google.ee/search?q=%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B&rlz=1C1AOHY_ruEE717EE717&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjG4OKDnfzTAhVJECwKHSXrDhsQsAQILg&biw=1422&bih=787)